# AWS network load balancer's TCP listener on port 80 isn't forwarding HTTP/2 requests properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I've got a GRPC server listening on port 8000 on an ec2 instance. If I put a network load balancer in front of it with a TCP listener on port 80, the HTTP/2 connection preface `PRI * HTTP/2.0` isn't being forwarded to my GRPC server (the other packets related to the HTTP/2 request do seem to arrive properly).

If I use a TCP listener on any port other than 80, everything works as expected -- the connection preface is sent properly and my requests are successful.

I've noticed that even if I delete my TCP listener for port 80, the load balancer still accepts connections on port 80 anyway.

My understanding was that a network load balancer would simply forward traffic -- is there something special about port 80?

Edit:

I created a network load balancer with no listeners as a test case just to show that port 80 is open and accepting connections of some sort even without attaching a listener:

```
$ aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --name somename --type network --subnets subnet-a1b2c3d4
$ aws elbv2 describe-listeners --load-balancer-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:somearn
{
    "Listeners": []
}
$ nmap somename-a1b2c3d4.elb.us-region-x.amazonaws.com

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-23 08:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for somename-a1b2c3d4.elb.us-region-x.amazonaws.com (123.255.255.255)
Host is up (0.019s latency).
rDNS record for 123.255.255.255: somename-a1b2c3d4.elb.us-region-x.amazonaws.com
Not shown: 986 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
1720/tcp open   h323q931
6000/tcp closed X11
6001/tcp closed X11:1
6002/tcp closed X11:2
6003/tcp closed X11:3
6004/tcp closed X11:4
6005/tcp closed X11:5
6006/tcp closed X11:6
6007/tcp closed X11:7
6009/tcp closed X11:9
6025/tcp closed x11
6059/tcp closed X11:59

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.01 seconds
```

Comment: My understanding of http2 is that all implementations are on port 443, rather than port 80. Perhaps you could double check the port, or try adding port 443 to see if it's being sent there.

Comment: I can see at least some traffic being received via port 80, just not the connection preface. I can also see that the connection preface is being sent to port 80. I'm not sure about HTTP/2 specifically, but the GRPC client I'm using forces you to specify the port and I can definitely see that the port is being used when I switch to 8000 and the requests are successful.

Comment: Given something still answers port 80 when you've disabled port 80 I suspect misconfiguration. Please edit your question to include EVERYTHING that could be needed for diagnostics - screenshots of NLB configuration, test cases, IP addresses, configuration files, etc. There's not enough in your question to provide a useful and reasonable answer. NLB doesn't care about the protocol, it works at layer 4 and http/2 is layer 7, making it pretty much invisible to the NLB. If you can't provide all the information requested you'll need to hire an AWS consultant.

Comment: I added the simplest test case I could think of. Hopefully it shows that the behavior I'm describing exists before configuring anything at all. I also thought that an NLB wouldn't care about the protocol, and that seems to be true on any other port.